# Suggestion for naming: Create-Edit-Dialog

Tags: design-patterns, refactoring

I often experience that the same classes / code is used to create and edit something (e.g. create / edit account settings).

I am looking for a best practice how to name folder / files / classes which are used for multiple use cases (like create and edit)

**EditDialog? CreateDialog? CreateEditDialog? FormDialog? SomethingBetter?**

*(FYI: I am currently developing an angular application)*

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: How about using _nouns_ to name them instead, e.g. AccountSettings?

Comment: Yes, but this is useally the name of the parent package:

Imagine something like:
App : AccountSettings : List / Detail / Create / Edit

(A list does only makes sense, if you have to manage multiple accounts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO FormDialog/Form is the best option you provided. In fact it is mentioning the type of the dialog that is a Form not a List and it also a good abstraction for a form is designed for editing and creating an entity.

But FormDialog may be too general because it can be an abstraction for many other operations other than Create and Edit. So it would be greate if you put a prefix for it when creating a new Dialog. For example, AccountSettings_FormDialog or AccountSettings_Form and DisableAccount_FromDialog or DisableAccount_Form.